# Regex's OR operator doesn't work

Tags: regex, validation

I have a pattern of regex that should match input that way:

```
123 -> Correct
123,456 -> Correct
012 -> Incorrect
012,345 -> Incorrect
```

I'm trying to achieve this with the following regex:

```
([1-9][0-9]*)|([1-9][0-9]*[,][0-9]{1,3})
```

OR operator doesn't work for some reason. Separately both work right, but not together. Why?

Comment: most of the time is just your code which does not work, not language constructs...

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

You need to add line delimiters otherwise, the regex will try to match anywhere on the string (thus, ignoring the fact that it starts with an 0):

```
^(([1-9][0-9]*)|([1-9][0-9]*[,][0-9]{1,3}))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bELIFk/1

(note that in your example, `([1-9][0-9]*[,][0-9]{1,3})` matches the last sample, meaning that the OR operator is not the issue)

---

### Bonus

But I think, this is what you are trying to do in a much simpler version:

```
^[1-9]\d*(,\d{1,3})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Jo41jj/3

Comment: Yes didn't take much time to try to improve it. Just done that, thanks for bringing attention to that.

Comment: BTW, your bonus expression also validates string like a23,123
I assume expression like `^[1-9]\d*(,\d{1,3})?$` validates it right

Answer (score 1):

The `regex` you provided matches your strings. Since it doesn't contain any [anchor](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php), it matches fragments of the input strings.

It matches `12` from `012` and `12,345` from `012,345`.

If you want it to match the entire string (or fail) you have to enclose it in `^` (matches the beginning of the string) and `$` (matches the end of the string).

The correct `regex` is:

```
^([1-9][0-9]*)|([1-9][0-9]*[,][0-9]{1,3})$
```

#### Remarks

The comma (`,`) is not a special character in `regex`, there is no need to put it in a range. `,` is the same as `[,]`.

The fragment before comma is common on both subexpressions. You can use the [zero or one repetition operator (`?`)](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) to write an expression that matches a number (`[1-9][0-9]*`) optionally (`(...)?`) followed by comma and 1 to 3 digits (`,[0-9]{1,3}`).

The `regex` is:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(,[0-9]{1,3})?$
```